# Can't adjust sound for internal sound card anymore

Tags: drivers, sound, 15.04, pulseaudio, alsa

Weird problem just appeared. I'm on **x64 15.04**, **Lenovo T410**, with driver **snd_hda_intel** and my sound does not work anymore, in the sense that the indicator on top is greyed out, and has an "x" next to the speaker icon. If I press the indicator the "mute" option is enabled, and clicking it has no effect.

The weird thing is that it *plays sound*, but I can't change the volume levels, neither with the indicator or with buttons on the laptop case. I recently updated the kernel with dist-upgrade so that could be the problem maby. System settings -> Output -> does not show any available output-options. Thanks for suggestions guys.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A2`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:215e]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Output of sudo cat `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-oss.conf`:

```
   blacklist ac97
blacklist ac97_codec
blacklist ac97_plugin_ad1980
blacklist ad1848
blacklist ad1889
blacklist adlib_card
blacklist aedsp16
blacklist ali5455
blacklist btaudio
blacklist cmpci
blacklist cs4232
blacklist cs4281
blacklist cs461x
blacklist cs46xx
blacklist emu10k1
blacklist es1370
blacklist es1371
blacklist esssolo1
blacklist forte
blacklist gus
blacklist i810_audio
blacklist kahlua
blacklist mad16
blacklist maestro
blacklist maestro3
blacklist maui
blacklist mpu401
blacklist nm256_audio
blacklist opl3
blacklist opl3sa
blacklist opl3sa2
blacklist pas2
blacklist pss
blacklist rme96xx
blacklist sb
blacklist sb_lib
blacklist sgalaxy
blacklist sonicvibes
blacklist sound
blacklist sscape
blacklist trident
blacklist trix
blacklist uart401
blacklist uart6850
blacklist via82cxxx_audio
blacklist v_midi
blacklist wavefront
blacklist ymfpci
blacklist ac97_plugin_wm97xx
blacklist ad1816
blacklist audio
blacklist awe_wave
blacklist dmasound_core
blacklist dmasound_pmac
blacklist harmony
blacklist sequencer
blacklist soundcard
blacklist usb-midi
```

Output of `cat /proc/version`:

```
Linux version 3.19.0-28-generic (buildd@lgw01-03) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) ) #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015
```

EDIT: Also, I've tried restarting Ubuntu with no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I fixed it by reinstalling `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio` with apt-get. Now everything works fine and there is even "speakers" in the output-section of the sound system settings. I think maybe my headphones was the culprit.